# Clicking Android's Back button launches a previously running app

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, launcher

Sometimes, when users click Android's Back button to exit an app, the app exits, but a previously loaded app will suddenly start running (even though the user launched the current app directly from the launcher).

Is there a solution to fix this?

*In the comments below, a specific example was requested...*

Here is a specific example from a friend's device: He is running [Lightning Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pierrox.lightning_launcher_extreme) on Android KitKat.  He will play [Sky Force 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd) and then after playing for a while, will launch another app to do something else.  When he exits the other app (happens with various apps) by pressing Android's Back button, Sky Force 2014 loads up again.

Comment: Does it happen with a custom launcher or with a particular app? Could you mention the names of them? I would like to test them out.

Comment: Happens with me occasionally when pressing home - what Android version/device do you have?

Comment: @Firelord Per your request, I added an example above.

Comment: @JoshHolland Per your request, I specified the Android version in the question.  I'm not sure exactly what device he is using.  It's very interesting that it happens to you sometimes when pressing Android's Home button.

Comment: I have now personally seen this issue happening on multiple Android devices.